# php xpath parse script src

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I am trying to parse all script src link values, but I get an empty array.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$file = @$dom->loadHTML($remote);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$link = $xpath->query('//script[contains(@src, "pcode")]');

$return = array();
foreach($link as $links) {
  $return[] = $links->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Without input sample this is not a real question. Besides that if those `script` have `@src` they shouldn't have content, you are using the wrong DOM method. See [`textContent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) from DOM level 3.

Comment: @Alejandro i don't want the content just the links

Comment: If by "link" you mean the `src` attribute, then you should be selecting them with `//script/@src[contains(.,"pcode")]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPATH query looks valid, should grab every `<script>` with attribute `src` containing `pcode`.

If it's returning an empty array, there's a few things to check:

Make sure the DOM document and loading, and there are not errors when loading it into XPATH. It could be possible that the suppressed DOM->load is giving an error or warning. If you query elsewhere and it works, then ignore this.

Make sure the tags in your document are case-matching.

Try

```
$link = $xpath->query("//script[contains(@src, 'pcode')]");
```

Seems silly, just switching quote marks, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check namespaces.  If your HTML contains a declaration like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You'll need to register the namespace with the document

```
$xp = new domxpath( $xml);
$xp->registerNamespace('html', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' );
```

And Look for  elements like this

```
$elements = $xp->query( "//html:script", $xml );
```

Namespaces, because paranoia breeds confidence.